# How to create taxonomy term count block?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have a blog in Drupal 7 where the blog content type has a multi-select box (select drop-down box) for tagging that uses a specific taxonomy vocabulary. As such, any blog entry can have multiple tags from the vocabulary by control-clicking the terms. What I need is a block that lists the terms with the count of the number of times the term has been used

Ex:

- Drupal (21)
- Views (15)
- Panels (18)

I also need each list item to link to a page that lists the blog titles associated with the term. I thought the first part would be simple using views with aggregation but, so far, no luck. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Taxonomy Views.
2. Add relationship to the node.
3. Enable grouping (or "Use aggregation" toggle in D7, then set the "Aggregation Settings" for each field)
4. Add new field 'Node: NID' and set Group type to: Count

Regards.